# Logging to Azure WADSLog table from independent Web application

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-roles

I have an independent MVC Web application which is not part of either the web or worker roles of my tenant.But this MVC application is also published as part of deployment.

I want this MVC web application to log to WADSLog table. Is that possible? How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

WADSLog table is like any other table in your table storage. You can just use Storage Client library to write to that table. Only thing you will have to ensure is that this table exists in the storage account. Diagnostics agent running in Azure Cloud Service creates this table for you but you can simply create this table on your own as well.

Comment: So I should not be using trace.Write any more? I should create my custom class to collect the logs and update it to WADLogs table?

Comment: Yes but its a bit more complicated than you think. Essentially every time you do Trace.Write equivalent, you don't want to save the data in storage. As its a network call, it comes with its own overhead. You would need to implement some kind of buffering mechanism so that data is written to the buffer and then periodically the buffer is written into table storage. I would recommend using 3rd party logging library like NLog or something. Also I would recommend that you take a look at how Azure Diagnostics agent works.